# Нужна ли запятая в сложносочинённом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

Предложение является хоть и сложносочинённым, но у меня появилось сомнение по поводу запятой.

"Как оказалось, рядом с барбарисом рос шиповник(,) и его шипы глубоко впились под кожу животного".

Comment: Джин, на сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая в подобных ситуациях позволяет автору относить либо не относить предложения к общему сочетанию. Взгляните на пример: ‟Хаджи-Мурат так задумался, что не заметил, как нагнул кувшин, и вода лилась из него”. При наличии запятой, Хаджи-Мурат не заметил только то, как нагнул кувшин; при отсутствии запятой, Хаджи-Мурат не заметил то, как нагнул кувшин и как вода лилась из него.
В подобных случаях лучше давать контекст, дабы было более ясно то, станет ли автор относить оба предложения к одному сочетанию. Ваше предложение, скорее всего, идет после предложения с информацией о том, что собака издала болезненный визг, — так что сочетание ‟как оказалось” будет относится и к тому, что рос шиповник, и к тому, что он впился собаке в кожу.
Правильная пунктуация следующая: ‟Как оказалось, рядом с барбарисом рос шиповник и его шипы глубоко впились под кожу животного”.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ 

Comment: Спасибо на хлеб не намажешь и в общее количество очков на сайте не зачислишь.

Comment: А так ли вам нужны эти очки?

Answer (score 1):

***Как оказалось,** рядом с барбарисом рос шиповник, и его шипы глубоко впились под кожу животного.*

В данном случае вводное сочетание "как оказалось" логичнее отнести только **к первому предложению**, так как между двумя предложениями в ССП явно подчеркивается **причинно-следственная связь.**

Важно также отметить, что автор изображает **две ситуации достаточно подробно** (рос шиповник, его шипы впились). Соответственно, **распространенные** предложения сложно прочесть в одну фонетическую фразу без паузы.

Сравнить: ***Как оказалось**, рядом рос шиповник и собака поранилась острым шипом.*

Таким образом, контекст здесь не так уж обязателен, а спрашивать у автора, что он имел в виду, тоже не стоит. Решение можно обосновать **структурой предложения.**